# For iterator is not being recognized in struts 2 execute method?

Tags: java, struts2

I  have this execute method action for struts2 in my program, it validates a login form in my webpage, checking an ArrayList called listaUsuarios where my usuarioBean objects are being stored, to find if the username and the password are equal in those attributes

```
public String executeLogin() {

    String go = ERROR;

    for (Usuario u : s.getListaUsuarios()) {
        if (usuarioBean.getNombreUsuario().equals(u.getNombreUsuario())) {
            if (usuarioBean.getContrasenna().equals(u.getContrasenna())) {
                if (u instanceof Administrador) {
                   go="admin";
                   break;
                }
                if (u instanceof Cliente) {
                   go="cliente";
                   break;
                }
                if (u instanceof Proveedor) {
                   go="proveedor"; 
                   break;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    return go;
}
```

This doesn't work, it doesn't validate anything but if I put in my login form, this hardcoded method, it works, so I'm not sure what is happening:

```
   public String executeLogin() {

    String go = ERROR;

    if (usuarioBean.getNombreUsuario().equals("jean182")) {
        if (usuarioBean.getContrasenna().equals("123")) {
            go = "admin";
        }
    }
     return go;
}
```

Comment: You could put a breakpoint or a print before the line 'return go' to see what is being stored at that moment. It can help you to find out what is happening.

Comment: it doesn't work tells nothing about what question is. Partial code without any clue what is this code doing, lack of details makes it completely impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you print the string you read from the form? The problem could be that those are not equals to the ones stored (spaces at the end, upper case / lower case)